# Is there any way to implement DKI in Squarespace landing pages or I must create 800 pages with different title manually?

Tags: javascript, keyword, google-ads-api, squarespace, insertion

Well, as in title; I want to implement dynamic keyword insertion into my Squarespace landing pages, I know how bad this engine is but well, it's for a company though. Last time I created 100 landing pages with different title and description etc, now I am slightly worried that 800 is a little bit too much for a manual work. All I can do in Squarespace is just javascript within the body, maybe you know how to actually utilize this opportunity.

Is it possible to use dynamic keyword insertion in Squarespace landing pages?

PS: Do yourself a favour, don't use Squarespace, never. Beaver builder + Wordpress > Squarespace

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible using [developer mode](https://developers.squarespace.com/quick-start) and a small misuse of the Squarespace [`tag` and/or `category` URL queries](https://developers.squarespace.com/url-queries/). For example, you could:

1. Create ads using DKI
2. Create a custom layout ([.region](https://developers.squarespace.com/layouts-regions/) or [.block](https://developers.squarespace.com/template-partials/)) using JSON-T. Somewhere in your page, you'd include `{categoryFilter}` or `{tagFilter}`. Similar to Mustache.js, wherever you insert that reference in your template, the value of the `category` or `tag` query parameter will be inserted. This could be used to set the `title` tag on the page or meta description for example.
3. Append `?category=My Keyword Text` (or `?tag=...`) to the destination URL of the ad.

**Notes**:

- The head of your template will likely reference the `{squarespace-headers}` tag. This is necessary for your Squarespace site to run properly (at least, unless you invest hours into breaking it down into its various components, which has been done, but then requires ongoing maintenance). This will contain its own `title` and meta description tags as well as other meta that may be working against you. You may have to experiment with forcing your own `title` and meta description by adding your own code above and/or below `{squarespace-headers}`. Your page will have multiple such tags; it's been said [Google will ignore subsequent ones](https://moz.com/ugc/google-serp-test-multiple-page-title-meta-description-tags).
- All Squarespace websites have [an identical robots.txt](https://www.squarespace.com/robots.txt), and it is not editable. URLs containing `tag=` are `disallow`ed. On the other hand, `category=` was recently removed from this disallow-list. That may influence which you use, if you attempt this route at all.
- A Squarespace site can have up to 1000 pages, but [they don't recommend adding more than 400](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206543087-Page-limits). That may influence your approach as well.
- As mentioned, this is a misuse of the tag and category filter URL queries, but these are the only query parameters that allow you to insert essentially whatever values you want and have those values accessible from within the templating engine. The `category` and `tag` URL queries are intended for collections, not pages, but the value works across all Squarespace page types that I've tested. Depending on your application, it could be that creating a collection of items and having a legitmate category/tag filter may be a relevant approach.
- You could attempt to do this all with Javascript-based templating, but I am assuming you're looking to render the page, with keywords, server-side.
- Squarespace's templating engine, JSON-T, doesn't have logic such as `if value contains X...`. This will limit the degree of flexibility you have if trying to render different content based on the keyword. You can check for equality via `{.equal?...}`, though I doubt that's practical for your application, given the number of possibilities. Of course, you can insert the keyword itself as mentioned previously.
- Although I have a lot of experience with Squarespace and developer mode, I've not attempted this specific scenario myself, so this is more theoretical than from experience.

Comment: Hi Brandon,
Thank you for helping me with this. I will try to follow your guidelines in minutes, but could you please tell me if developer mode will reset my website totally? I already established the website, but I am not sure if I will turn it on, it will crash.

Edit: I think I have found the solution! It is this one: https://jennamolby.com/how-to-display-dynamic-content-on-a-page-using-url-parameters/
But I am not sure why it does not work when the custom URL parameter has more than 1 word :/.

Comment: You can turn on dev. mode and everything on your site should remain as-is. There are some anomalies with this. There is risk, though it's always worked reliably for me. Turning on dev. mode disconnects your template from future Squarespace-issued template updates (that can be a good thing or a bad thing, depending on how you look at it; I prefer it). The Javascript-based solution you mentioned will also work (my 5th bullet), but may not perform as well with regards to SEO, quality score, UX and appearance in SERPs. But it is less complex, so that would have to be weighed.

Comment: Pages created this way would be visible only for paid traffic so in this case, SEO does not matter that match, it is more like a problem because long-tail keywords in the url looks like this: https://www.sunstudio.london/printed-mirrors-testing?keyword=grey%20splashback
And javascript I have mentioned, simply shows the default value, I don't know what to do next though.